# Not able to install pandas for python 2.7 on centos

Tags: python, pandas, pip

While Installing pandas for python 2.7 getting the below error.

```
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata5_115.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test4.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test_converters.xlsm -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata1_114.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata11_115.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata3_114.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test2.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/testskiprows.xlsm -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/blank_with_header.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata6.csv -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata6_113.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test_types.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test1.xls -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test_types.xls -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test_converters.xls -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata8_117.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/testdtype.xlsm -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata4_117.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/testdtype.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata15.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/blank.xls -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata13_dates.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata12_117.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata5_113.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/banklist.csv -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata6_117.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test5.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test3.xlsm -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/wikipedia_states.html -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata5.csv -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test3.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata3.csv -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/test_index_name_pre17.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/stata3_115.dta -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/spam.html -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
copying pandas/tests/io/data/times_1904.xlsx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tests/io/data
**error: can't copy 'pandas/tests/io/data/legacy_hdf': doesn't exist or not a regular file**

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-RuAQlC/pandas/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-tj_y77/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-RuAQlC/pandas/

Tried almost everything.

pip install --user pandas

pip is pointing to python2. so that is not an issue.